# VHDL if condition not working properly

Tags: vhdl

I'm having some difficulties determining why my code is not working properly. I'm trying to create an ALU with a 3-bit op-code.

All but one condition doesn't work properly; op code 011 (SEQ). It's defined as if(a==b) z<='0' and output<='0'. a and b are the inputs, and z is the zero flag. I expected to get this functionality with the following VHDL code

```
....
    BEGIN

    result <= dummy_result;

    PROCESS (a, b, op) 

        VARIABLE carry: STD_LOGIC:='0';

         --DEFINE ALIAS TO SEPERATE ALU-OP SIGNAL
        alias NEG_TSEL      : STD_LOGIC IS op(2);
        alias ALU_SELECT    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0) IS op(1 downto 0);
    BEGIN
         if ALU_SELECT="11" THEN

                if NEG_TSEL='0'  THEN   -- SEQ

                    if a = b THEN
                        dummy_result <="00000";
                    end if;

                elsif NEG_TSEL='1' THEN     --SCO

                    cout <= '1';
                    result <= "XXXXX";


                end if;


        elsif ALU_SELECT="00" THEN...
```

With this code, when op = 011, results is always set to zero.

When I change the code to:

```
            .....
            if a = b THEN
                dummy_result <="00000";

            else
                dummy_result <= "10101";
            end if;
.....
```

it works fine, but results must not change so instead of the "10101" vector, I change it to "dummy_result <= dummy_result;" but that gives me the same results as the original case gives me.

Any suggestions? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @sharth, you are correct with the functionality. I've added the ALU code which might answer some questions.

Comment: "I was told not to use buffers" ... That happens a lot, but I challenge you to find a rational and sensible explanation why not... Also, what is supposed to happen in opcode 011 when a /= b? Also note : you test a=b twice in that branch, one of those tests is redundant.

Comment: For a/=b, the results should not change. Logically, other than the "others" for the case statement, aren't the statements the same? Or will the hardware use be different? It was my understanding that if you don't change an output then it remains the same. Is this a bad style? Should i always be setting the outputs? Without changing the entity definition, how would i go about saving the results/dummy_results?

Comment: It is a bad style outside a clocked process. Yes "the results should not change" but the hardware to implement unclocked storage - a latch - is likely to be troublesome and some synthesis tools may not implement it reliably. In simulation I would expect "result" not to change but what happens when different bits of a and b change at different speeds and a=b momentarily by accident?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my issues with your code:

Personally, I feel that on every cycle you should be outputting something to `result`, `cout`, and `zero`. Currently, you always output to `zero`, but you only conditionally output to the other two ports. This likely is creating latches, which is probably not what you want. So, for example, the SCO operation, should also push something to `cout`, and the SCO operation should push something to the `dummy_result` signal.

Your subtraction implementation is not working how you might expect.

```
when "110" => -- SUB
    tmp_b <= NOT b;
    carry := '1';

    for i in 0 to 4 loop
        dummy_result(i) <= carry XOR a(i) XOR tmp_b(i);
        carry := (a(i) AND tmp_b(i)) OR (tmp_b(i) AND carry) OR (carry AND a(i));
    end loop;
    cout <= carry;
```

`tmp_b` is a signal. The logic that happens there will happen concurrently with everything else in this process, not sequentially. You likely want that to be a variable, just like `carry` is.

---

I also wanted to let you know about case statements (versus if chains). Your code could look like this:

```
PROCESS (a, b, op)
    VARIABLE carry: STD_LOGIC:='0';
BEGIN

    case op is
        when "011" => -- SEQ
            dummy_result <= "00000";

        when "111" => -- SCO
            cout <= '1';

        when "000" => -- AND
            dummy_result <= a AND b;

        ...

        when others =>
            dummy_result <= "00000";
            cout <= '0';
    end case;
end process;
```

---

To get back to the original problem, `SEQ`, your original code looked like:

```
when op = "011" =>
    if a = b then
        dummy_result <= "00000";
    end if;
```

The problem here, as I mentioned above, is that this is likely a latch. You need to output what you expect the value to be when a /= b, and that can't just be `dummy_result <= dummy_result`. What do you expect that to become if you pushed it to physical wires and chips?

Instead, you should pass into this entity the value of the last dummy_result, or if a particular operation should hold the value of result, you should output "00000" and also output an additional signal saying that whatever is *holding* the previous value (in a register), shouldn't update it.

Answer (score 0):

The intent here is that unless otherwise assigned, dummy_result is intended to retain the previous value of "result". Unfortunately, this unit has been implemented as a combinational process, without a clock.

Therefore the storage cannot be reliably implemented in this unit.
Therefore it must be implemented outside this unit.
It almost certainly already is; in a register implemented as a clocked process.

So, bring that register's output back in as a new input port "prev_result" and use a default assignment to dummy_result. That will overcome not only the specific failure you have found so far, but all the other missing assignments to "dummy_result" (there is another) preserving the old value for "result" in a synchronous manner.

```
    PROCESS (a, b, op, prev_result) 
       -- declarations here
    BEGIN
       -- default assignment
       dummy_result <= prev_result;

       if ALU_SELECT="11" THEN
          if NEG_TSEL='0' THEN    -- SEQ
             if a = b THEN
                dummy_result <="00000";
             end if;
       ...
    END PROCESS;
```

I think you would be better restructuring the design to make the ALU a clocked process, but if you are under instructions not to, then you will have to adopt this (or similar) solution.

Comment: The entity value must not change (unfortunately). I applied this method to both cout and results which got rid of the latch warnings. But in order to retain the last value or have nothing happen to the output results, am I not still stuck with using latches?  I'm just a bit confused about how **prev_result** would get set without inferring an infinite loop.

Comment: prev_result MUST be sourced from a clocked register - you either need to bring it in from outside or (naughty! ALUs are supposed tobe combinational) bring in the clock signal so you can do it inside. Either way the entity must change. Failing that I would assign (others=> 'X') to prev_result which will ensure anyone using the improperly defined signals will catch them in simulation. If this is a homework assignment or project, my recommendation is to find a better school...